# c++ when assigning an object private

Tags: c++, class

all. I'm new to c++, and I want to ask a question about assign an object.

for example
I have 2 objects that come from same class , a1 and a2.
and if there are some private member in the class

why can we do the assignment like this
a1 = a2;

my question is that, I thought only member function has the authority 
to change the content of the private member data, but through the steps
i just go through, the private member data is easily changed.
Why is that??

Comment: Thank you guys!
I think I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. But in the case you outlined, you call a member function of a1. The public member function `YourClass& operator=(const <YourClass>& rightHandSide)` to be specific. If you didn't provide it by yourself, the compiler automatically generated such a method. If you want to prevent the compiler from generating one and strictly do NOT want assignment the way described above, just declare `operator=` private and don't provide a definition at all. This will cause the compiler to complain at `a1 = a2`.

Another thing that can be confusing is that question how exactly the method `operator=` can read the private data of the rhs. This is exactly has Luchian Grigore has outlined: they are private to the class, not to the instance.

Answer (score 5):

The assignment can be performed using the `operator=` member function, which by definition has access to private members.

When you don't define one, a default is provided: "The default version performs a memberwise copy, where each member is copied by its own copy assignment operator (which may also be programmer-declared or compiler-generated)." See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_in_C%2B%2B).

Answer (score 2):

The caller doesn't know what's being copied, other than "the object". The caller does not know that there are any private members at all. The *assignment operator* is public, and the behavior is the same for any public method -- public methods can of course modify private members.

Answer (score 2):

Private members and methods are restricted to the class, not to a specific instance. You can access private members in a different class instance from an object of the same class. This behavior is by design and is guaranteed by the standard.

If you haven't overwritten the assignment operator (`A& A::operator = (const A& other)`) you're most likely doing a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

a1 = a2; in this case a implicit "copy assignment operator" of a1 object (i.e target object)is called which is public and present in both a1 and a2. job of "copy assignment operator" is to copy all the data members from one object to another.